# Object Composition and Hibernate Save/Update

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate and I'm hoping for a little help. When performing a saveOrUpdate() I am not getting the behavior I'd expect. Perhaps it is my expectations that need adjustment.

When preforming the following saveOrUpdate(), the Building table is not affected:

```
Buildings building = new Buildings(bldgInfoArg.getBldgId());
building.setBldgNumber(bldgInfoArg.getBldgNumber());

BuildingInfos bldgInfo = new BuildingInfos(null,
        building,       
        bldgInfoArg.getTblAbbreviation(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblBldgName(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblStreetAddress(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblStateCode(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblZipCode(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblMajorBuilding(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblFirstEffectiveAt(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblLastEffectiveAt(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblCity(),
        bldgInfoArg.getTblZipCodeExtension());

bldgInfoSssn.saveOrUpdate(bldgInfo);
```

Instead of updating the Building table with the building object, only the BuildingInfo table is affected.  Of course, I know that I can also perform the saveOrUpdate() on the Building table, but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.  In this example it's not a big deal, but in other cases it could be more annoying.

Comment: post `BuildingInfos` and `Buildings` code if they are annotated otherwise post their hbm.xml

Comment: You need to add cascade options to the buildinginfo table on Building property.

Comment: The cascade property was helpful, thank you.